# PYTHON: How to receive data continuously from a server that's using zmq Poller?

Tags: python, zeromq, poller

I am using simple requests.post() module to connect to a server and receive data

```
ack = requests.post('<ip>/get_data, data=data, timeout=10.0, verify=False)
```

Below is a method get_data() in server that's using zmq poller to receive data until final response is obtained.

```
def get_data():
    req = json.loads(self.params.get('data'))
    wire = wiring.Wire("indexing_data_pool", zmq_context=g.zmq_context)
    try:
        close_immediately = True
        poll_agent = zmq.Poller()
        poll_agent.register(wire.socket, zmq.POLLIN)
        wire.send(req)
        iteration = 1
        while True:
            socks = dict(poll_agent.poll())
            if wire.socket in socks and socks[wire.socket] == zmq.POLLIN:
                res = gevent.with_timeout(10, wire.recv, timeout_value=None)
                if res.get('final'):
                    log.warn('Last Iteration: %s, Length of Rows: %s' %(iteration, len(res['rows'])))
                    break
                else:
                    log.warn('Iteration: %s, Length of Rows: %s' %(iteration, len(res['rows'])))
                    next_req = {'search_id': req['search_id'], 'seen_version':res.get('response_version')}
                    wire.send(next_req)
                iteration +=1
    finally:
        wire.close(immediate=close_immediately)
        poll_agent.unregister(wire.socket)
```

In server side, the response obtained is logged as below:

```
2017-08-28_07:17:55.43370 WARNING: Iteration: 1, Length of Rows: 100
2017-08-28_07:17:55.44269 WARNING: Iteration: 2, Length of Rows: 100
2017-08-28_07:17:55.44894 WARNING: Iteration: 3, Length of Rows: 100
2017-08-28_07:17:55.45742 WARNING: Iteration: 4, Length of Rows: 100
2017-08-28_07:17:55.46327 WARNING: Iteration: 5, Length of Rows: 100
2017-08-28_07:17:55.46687 WARNING: Iteration: 6, Length of Rows: 100
2017-08-28_07:17:55.47074 WARNING: Iteration: 7, Length of Rows: 100
2017-08-28_07:17:55.47658 WARNING: Iteration: 8, Length of Rows: 100
2017-08-28_07:17:55.48385 WARNING: Last Iteration: 9, Length of Rows: 75
```

So, I assume that the zmq poller I have implemented in server side is working perfectly fine. But, I am curious to know how to send back these 9 iterations of data back to the requesting client?

> P.S. I want to receive the data continuously in client side. You may
>   suggest appending each batch of response somewhere and sending the
>   final response back to the client. This won't be feasible when the
>   response is too big (The requesting client would get timeout)

Comment: Ok, I handled this using Response object from Flask module. Invoking a separate method that'd yield the data continuously and making the final Response object and returning it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, 
I handled this using Response object from Flask module. Invoking a separate method that'd yield the data continuously and making the final Response object and returning it solved my problem.